# Why can't I use an optocoupler to drive an AC circuit using the arduino digital pins?

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

So, when I searched for ways to drive AC circuits from Arduino, everyone suggested relays with a transistor switching circuit to channel an external 5V. I was wondering what would happen if I used an optocoupler like 4n35 to drive an AC circuit. Will the phototransistor inside the chip burn out?

Comment: Which AC voltage?

Comment: 220 V AC mains I meant

Comment: Maximum current is 50mA, so not that useful in most cases.

Comment: From what you are typing, I guess you are neither an electrician or somehow experienced in this matter. Dealing with mains voltage, in particular building circuitry working with mains voltage requires substantial knowlede to avoid deadly risks as accidental electrocution and fire hazards. In fact in most countries you sail close to the wind doing so without. You face administrative fines up to imprisonment in case of injury to persons. I strongly recommend you fetch some basics about electrical safety and your local regulatory legislation before continuing with what you had in mind.

Comment: @Gerben: at least 11 W :) (and the thermal energy of the burning plastic housing).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I want intending to try this. Just needed a theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use it with Triac.  I use MOC3020 + BT138 + 330 and 510 Ohm resistors.
It works good as relay and in dimmer scheme.
Scheme is here 
http://cyber-place.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=1030&d=1370462030

Answer (score 1):

No. A 4N35 will switch 150mA at 30V DC. See http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits for more detail. If you are proposing to switch 110/240V AC there are safety issues. You should look at available commercial modules.

Answer (score 1):

Normally Opto couplers like a 4N35 were not designed to drive an application load.  Typically they are used to trigger another device such as a SCR or Triac.  There is a vidio I would recommend you watch, it gives some information and the comments are good.  Give this a try:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVef6f2_Si8

Gil

Answer (score 1):

SSR's typically have a arduino friendly 3v + dc input, and can switch 10+ amps of up to 330vac.